# ansible can't get inventory_hostname

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I'm trying to get the short name of a server being worked on.

I have this in jinja2:

```
ServerAlias graphite.{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] }}
ServerAlias graphite.{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] }}.{{dc}}.{{subnet}}
```

The above just spills the whole glob of facts instead of just the short name.

This is what the hosts.yaml looks like:

```
graphite.experimental.com dc=lv1 subnet=coupons.lan
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you want to use is just `{{ inventory_hostname }}` (or `{{ inventory_hostname_short }}` for the short name).

The `hostvars` object is a way to access the variables of every host that Ansible knows about.  So `hostvars[inventory_hostname]` will give you the object containing all known facts about the current host, `hostvars['foo']` will give you the object containing all the known facts about the host 'foo', etc.

Suppose you have a group of hosts called 'db_servers' and you wanted to generate a list of the IP addresses of all those hosts in a template.  Here's how you would do that:

```
{% for host in groups['db_servers'] %}
   {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this led me to use {{ ansible_hostname }}. Thank you!